# Is there any risk associated with trustworthy database for SQLCLR (Assembly) implementation?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, security, sqlclr

I need to write a SQLCLR function to access an external file. I have done it by giving `trustworthy on` to my database. Is there any other way to access external resources without giving `trustworthy on` ?  Is there any risk associated with trustworthy database for SQLCLR implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For avoiding `TRUSTWORTHY ON` to a database for access external resources, follow procedures:

```
USE MASTER;
CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY '<youKeyName>' FROM EXECUTABLE FILE = '<Your dll file path>';
CREATE LOGIN '<yourUserName>' FROM ASYMMETRIC KEY '<yourKeyName>';
GRANT EXTERNAL ACCESS ASSEMBLY TO '<yourUserName>';
USE '<YOUR DB NAME>';
CREATE ASSEMBLY '<Assembly name>' FROM '<Your dll file path>'
    WITH PERMISSION_SET = EXTERNAL_ACCESS;
```

Try this :)-

Answer (score 3):

There is a risk, but it's small if you control all the code that is present in the database.  You need to set trustworthy to on if you are using the external_access or unsafe permissions for assemblies because otherwise SQL server literally won't trust your code and won't let it go outside of the instance.

Here is a link from Microsoft detailing some guidelines for setting the trustworthy flag:

[Guidelines for using the TRUSTWORTHY database setting in SQL Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2183687)

Comment: Thanks dude... From the above link i got what i need.

Comment: No worries, if the information I provided answered your question, please mark the answer as accepted, it helps everyone out.